# What's wrong with my javascript? .className

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a navigation and my goal is that when you click a link, it will change the class to .nav-link-active while changing the current .nav-link-active back to .nav-link.

Heres my code:

```
<header>
<nav>
<div class="nav-link-active" onclick="activeNavLink();"><a href="#index">Home</a></div>
<div class="nav-link" onclick="activeNavLink();"><a href="#services">Services</a></div>
<div class="nav-link" onclick="activeNavLink();"><a href="#info">Info</a></div>
<div class="nav-link" onclick="activeNavLink();"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></div>
</nav>
</header>
<script type="text/javascript">
var revert = "nav-link";
var active = "nav-link-active";
function removeActive() {
    var elRevert = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link-active");
    elRevert.className = revert;
}
function setActive() {
    var elSet = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link");
    elSet.className = active;
}
function activeNavLink() {
    removeActive();
    setActive();
}
</script>
```

This will probably be an easy fix for someone but this is my first time writing javascript and i have no clue what's wrong.

EDIT:
Thanks to all who replied, much respect. Now time for me to go bury my face back in this book.

Comment: Read about css solution https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/active/

Comment: why are you setting it as 'revert'? don't you want to set it as nav-link?

Comment: your set active seems like it will set them all active...

Comment: i like to cut-down code and avoid inline JS using delegation: https://jsfiddle.net/se8bbcxb/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
var elSet = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link");
```

the above code returns `nodelist`.so `elSet.className = active;` wont work.so change your `setActive` and `activaNavLink` to .

```
function setActive(ele) {
  ele.className = active;
}
function activeNavLink(ele) {
 removeActive();
 setActive(ele);
}
```

and in your html

```
<div class="nav-link" onclick="activeNavLink(this);"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></div>
```

Comment: setting a do-nothing property will NOT throw an error in JS.  usually at least, but including the case describe.

Comment: sorry . in that context i meant `error` as semantic error .Thanks for your comment...!i have corrected the code.

Comment: this is going to be a newbie questions but what does ELE stand for?

Comment: we are passing `this` obj to `activeNavLink` function and assigning it to `ele`.so `ele` now holds `this`object.(element which triggered the `actionNavLink`)

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-link-active" onclick="activeNavLink(this);"><a href="#index">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-link" onclick="activeNavLink(this);"><a href="#services">Services</a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-link" onclick="activeNavLink(this);"><a href="#info">Info</a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-link" onclick="activeNavLink(this);"><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

then

```
//pass the current element
function activeNavLink(el){
    var active = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-link-active');
    if(active && active.length){
        //change the previous element if present
        active[0].className = 'nav-link';
    }
    el.className ='nav-link-active'
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qwpjx4gu/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var revert = "nav-link";
var active = "nav-link-active";

//remove active from links
function removeActive() {
    var activeLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link-active");
    for(var i = 0; i < activeLinks.length; i++)
    {
      activeLinks[i].className = revert;
    }
}

//set active to given element
function setActive(t) {
  t.className = active;
}

//remove active from links and set active to clicked elements 
function activeNavLink(t) {
    removeActive();
    setActive(t);
}
```

```css
.nav-link-active{
  font-size:20px;
}
.nav-link{
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
<nav>
<div class="nav-link-active" onclick="activeNavLink(this);"><a href="#index">Home</a></div>
<div class="nav-link" onclick="activeNavLink(this);"><a href="#services">Services</a></div>
<div class="nav-link" onclick="activeNavLink(this);"><a href="#info">Info</a></div>
<div class="nav-link" onclick="activeNavLink(this);"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></div>
</nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are over engineering it, first you need to correct your HTML something like below.

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anjum121/se8bbcxb/3/)

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li ><a href="#index" onclick="addClass(this)" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Services" onclick="addClass(this)"> Services </a></li>
      <li><a href="#info" onclick="addClass(this)"> info </a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact" onclick="addClass(this)">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
 </header>
```

Add css

```
header ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
header ul li{
  list-style:none;
  display:block;
}
header ul li a{
   display:block;
   color:black;
   text-decoration :none
}
header ul li a.active{
    color:red;
   text-decoration :underline
}
```

You can use javascript like

```
function addClass(obj) {
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
// loop through all 'a' elements
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    // Remove the class 'active' if it exists
    a[i].classList.remove('active')
}
// add 'active' classs to the element that was clicked
obj.classList.add('active');
}
```